# If $f(x+y)=f(x)\cdot f(y)$, then $f(x)=e^{ax}$

Tags: real-analysis

I'm trying to prove this question:

> Let $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ a function such that $f(x+y)=f(x)\cdot
>  f(y)$, $f(0)=1$ and $f'(0)=a$. Show that $f(x)=e^{ax}$, for every
>   $x\in \mathbb R$.

First of all I'm trying to prove that this function is positive, but even that it's difficult to me, I know that this function is never zero, because if there is $y \in \mathbb R$ such that $f(y)=0$, then $f(x-y+y)=f(x-y)\cdot f(y)=0$, then $f(x)=0$ for every $x\in \mathbb R$.

I need help to prove the positivity and hints to follow from that point.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Show that $f$ is differentiable (in particular, continuous).

Comment: @QiaochuYuan what's the gain showing that? thank you for your comment.

Comment: If you can show that $f$ is continuous, $f(0) = 1$ together with the fact that $f$ is never zero implies that $f$ is positive.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

for positivity:

$f(x) = f(\frac{x}{2} +\frac{x}{2})=f^2(\frac{x}{2})\geq 0$

hint for the problem:

take $g(x) =\ln f(x)$ then $g(x+y) =g(x) +g(y)$ so $g(x) =ax$

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!!! you helped me a lot.

Comment: I think the last step needs a bit of justification.  Let $\mathbb{R}$ be thought of as a vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$.  Let $\{b_{-1}, b_0 = 1, b_1, ...\}$ be a basis and let $\phi(b_{-1}) = 1$ and $\phi(b_i) = 0$ for $i \geq 0$ and extend $\phi$ to be linear.  This is not of the form $\phi(x) = kx$ but it does satisfy $\phi(x + y) = \phi(x) + \phi(y)$.  At some point we need to use the differentiability condition.

Comment: How can you argue that $g(x+y)=g(x)+g(y)$ must have $g(x)=ax$?

Comment: user39843, we simply say $g'(0) = \frac{f'(0)}{f(0)} = a$ and so $\frac{g(x+h) - g(x)}{h} \rightarrow a$.  This means that $g'(x) = a$ and so $g(x) = ax$.

Comment: @user39843 we can prove that if $g(x+y)= g(x)+g(y)$, then $g(x)=\lambda x$ to see this, first of all prove to the natural numbers, after to the rational, irracional and to real numbers, did you follow me?

Comment: @user42912  && muzzlator  you're right

Answer (score 6):

Pardon me if my solution seems like a cop out

They've already said the derivative at $0$ is defined, so $\frac{f(h) - 1}{h} \rightarrow a$.

Now $\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} = f(x) \frac{f(h) - 1}{h}$ which as $h \rightarrow 0$ is $a f(x)$.  So $f'(x) = a f(x)$ and $f(0) = 1$.

This has solution $f(x) = e^{a x}$.